# VBA to paste copied cells while preserving the original formulas, with some exceptions for relative cell references within the copied range

Tags: excel, vba

this is my first ever time posting.

I'm in need of a bit of help as very often, I find myself having to copy and paste duplicate excel ranges, as I do not want to mess with the OG cells that drives the model.

I wrote the below code to make my life easier but I'm in need of a bit of help to tweak it. As it stands, based on Image-1/2, it should allow you to duplicate the exact formula to any cell range you wish to output to however, I'm having a bit of an issue (and have been trying to weeks to solve). I'm unable to get it to dynamically change the relative cell references within the copied range to maintain relative logic.

For example (based on Image-1/2), if I tried to copy cell B31:H32 to J31:P32, I want the formula for P32 to be =SUM($J31:P31) instead of =SUM($B31:H31) which is the exact same formula as H32.

Does that make sense? Can anyone help with this?

```vb
Sub DuplicateFormulas()
Dim sourceRng As Range
Dim targetCell As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim subCell As Variant

' Ensure a range is selected
If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then
MsgBox "Please select a range to duplicate first.", vbExclamation
Exit Sub
End If

Set sourceRng = Selection

' Prompt the user to select the destination cell
On Error Resume Next
Set targetCell = Application.InputBox("Select the destination cell:", "Duplicate Formulas", Type:=8)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not targetCell Is Nothing Then

' Iterate through each area in the source range (handles non-contiguous ranges)
For Each cell In sourceRng.Areas
' Iterate through each cell in the area
For Each subCell In cell
' Check if the cell is not empty
If Not IsEmpty(subCell.Value) Then
' Copy the formula to the corresponding cell relative to the target cell
targetCell.Offset(subCell.Row - sourceRng.Row, subCell.Column - sourceRng.Column).formula = subCell.formula

' Adjust relative references within the copied formula
AdjustRelativeReferences targetCell.Offset(subCell.Row - sourceRng.Row, subCell.Column - sourceRng.Column), sourceRng, targetCell

' Copy formatting (optional)
If subCell.HasFormula Then
targetCell.Offset(subCell.Row - sourceRng.Row, subCell.Column - sourceRng.Column).Copy
End If
End If
Next subCell
Next cell

' Paste formatting (optional)
If sourceRng.HasFormula Then
targetCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
End If

End If

End Sub

Sub AdjustRelativeReferences(targetCell As Range, sourceRng As Range, targetRng As Range)

Dim reference As Range
Dim adjustedFormula As String

' Iterate through each direct precedent (referenced cell) of the target cell
For Each reference In targetCell.DirectPrecedents
' Ensure reference is within the copied range
If Not Intersect(reference, sourceRng) Is Nothing Then
' Adjust the reference based on the difference between the source and target ranges
Set reference = targetRng.Worksheet.Cells(reference.Row + targetCell.Row - sourceRng.Row, reference.Column + targetCell.Column - sourceRng.Column)
' Adjust the formula dynamically to be relative
adjustedFormula = Replace(targetCell.formula, reference.Address, reference.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1))
adjustedFormula = Replace(adjustedFormula, sourceRng.Address, targetRng.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1))
targetCell.formula = adjustedFormula
End If
Next reference

End Sub
```

Image-1

[image: 1]

Image-2

[image: 2]

Nothing as worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

- Green cells is used for output validation. It does not affect the logic of code.
- Testing scenario: current selection is `$B$31:$H$32,$C$40:$I$41`, destination cell is `J31`.
- Output: two tables in yellow are same as selection.

***Note:*** `AdjustReferences()` is designed to manage the formulas mentioned in your post. Adjust it as necessary if the formulas differ.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub DuplicateFormulas()
    Dim sourceRng As Range
    Dim targetCell As Range
    Dim srcRng As Range
    '    Range("$B$31:$H$32,$C$40:$I$41").Select ' testing **
    ' Ensure a range is selected
    If TypeName(Selection) <> "Range" Then
        MsgBox "Please select a range to duplicate first.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Set sourceRng = Selection
    ' Prompt the user to select the destination cell
    On Error Resume Next
    Set targetCell = Application.InputBox("Select the destination cell:", "Duplicate Formulas", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    '    Set targetCell = [j31] ' testing **
    If Not targetCell Is Nothing Then
        Dim rOffset As Long, cOffset As Long, desAnchor As Range
        ' Get the row and col offset
        Set targetCell = targetCell.Cells(1)
        With sourceRng.Areas(1).Cells(1)
            rOffset = targetCell.Row - .Row
            cOffset = targetCell.Column - .Column
        End With
        ' Iterate through each area in the source range (handles non-contiguous ranges)
        For Each srcRng In sourceRng.Areas
            With srcRng
                ' top-left cell of destination
                Set desAnchor = .Cells(1).Offset(rOffset, cOffset)
                ' copy source area (range) to destination
                .Copy desAnchor
                ' update relative ref
                AdjustReferences .Cells(1), desAnchor.Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
            End With
        Next srcRng
    End If
End Sub

Sub AdjustReferences(srcAnchor As Range, desRng As Range)
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, aFormula
    Dim sSrcRef As String, sDesRef As String
    sSrcRef = srcAnchor.Address(False, True)
    With desRng
        sDesRef = .Cells(1).Address(False, True)
        aFormula = .Formula
        For i = 1 To UBound(aFormula)
            For j = 1 To UBound(aFormula, 2)
                aFormula(i, j) = Replace(aFormula(i, j), sSrcRef, sDesRef)
            Next
        Next
        .Formula = aFormula
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]